# I am Self Funded applying for Tier 4 Student Visa, how to avoid rejection?

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, uk-visa, study

I am from India applied for MSc in the UK, received an unconditional offer letter from the university and CAS Letter is going to be issued within a few days.

Regarding bank statements, everywhere it was told, Tier 4 General visa students need to submit a 28-old bank statement before the date of application.

I am self-funding my education and living expenses.

> because I am self-funded, Will ECO ask my Source of Funding and Longer bank statement of 3-6
>   months?

My Source of Funds:
(being honest here)

Since 3 years I worked with a UK company as a Contractor (freelancer, not official), and I have built their entire software which got me savings for my education now. Contract terminated in the previous month (May 2019)

> For Tier 4 Visa, Do I need to show/submit all my payslips/invoices from the UK company during the interview?

also

> Will they reject my Visa because I have worked with UK company thinking
>   I am going to settle in the UK after my graduation?

I have one email of contract termination from the employer,

> will this email conversation serve as a proof to tell that presently I don't have any relation with the previous employer?

I have filed my Income Tax Return for the 2018-19 financial year (not earlier) with showing high expenses in freelancing, So I can avoid paying high taxes, as I need to sustain my education finances in present.

> Do I need to submit my Income tax Returns? If yes, will they ask me
>   why I paid low taxes? Will they take a close look at all the expenses?

Please help! I am confused with a lot of questions, did a lot of research but couldn't find knowledgable answers.

Comment: Are your bank statements consistent with the expenses claimed on your tax return? Is the after-expense income sufficient to explain the bank balance?

Comment: Hi Patricia, thanks for your comment. I have checked with my accountant, and he mentioned yes for your above comment. I have filed tax returns, just to be on the safer side if they ask to submit the returns. Can you please also advise me about my other questions.

Comment: Tier 4 (General) applicants need to submit documents which show that the funds being used to meet the maintenance requirements have been held for a consecutive 28-day period (finishing on the date of the closing balance) ending no more than 31 days before your application and no later than the date of the application. Was all your work for the UK company done remotely? Clause 99 of https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/822984/T4_Migrant_Guidance_August_2019_.pdf refers to income earned in the UK

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
I received my VISA, and presently in the UK now.

So I submitted only Original Documents, as per my CAS Letter and the docs asked by UKVI office, nothing additional documents.

Comment: Are you the same person who asked the question? Please put that in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, missed that, I am the same person asked the above question.